# how to set formdata without controller in flutter?

Tags: flutter

After clicking the button to update _formData, why does the page not display the new value?

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class TestPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const TestPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _TestPageState createState() => _TestPageState();
}

class _TestPageState extends State<TestPage> {
  Map<String, String> _formData = { 
    'id': '',
    'title': '',
    'desc': '',
  };
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
        child: Column(
      children: [
        FilledButton(
            onPressed: () {
              setState(() {
                _formData['title'] = _getText();
              });
            },
            child: Text('test')),
        TextFormField(
          decoration: const InputDecoration(labelText: 'Title'),
          initialValue: _formData['title'],
          onSaved: (val) => _formData['title'] = val!,
        ),
        TextFormField(
          decoration: const InputDecoration(labelText: 'Description'),
          initialValue: _formData['desc'],
          onSaved: (val) => _formData['desc'] = val!,
        ),
      ],
    ));
  }
}

String _getText() {
  return DateTime.now().toString();
}
```

I need to fill in the selected product information into this form, there are about 20 fields, so I hope to use setData instead of the controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it seems like that `TextFormField` will not be updated after you call `setState()`, use `_formData['title']` as a key of `TextFormField` like below

```
          TextFormField(
            key: Key(_formData['title'] ?? ''),
            decoration: const InputDecoration(labelText: 'Title'),
            initialValue: _formData['title'],
            onSaved: (val) => _formData['title'] = val!,
          ),
```

then `TextFormField` will be updated every time you update `_formData['title']`

Comment: it works thanks!!!it worried me for a long time

Answer (score 0):

some changes in code, try below code :

```
class DemoScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const DemoScreen({super.key});

  @override
  State<DemoScreen> createState() => _DemoScreenState();
}

class _DemoScreenState extends State<DemoScreen> {
  final GlobalKey<FormState> _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>(); // Add this key

  Map<String, String> _formData = {
    'id': '',
    'title': '',
    'desc': '',
  };

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Form(
        key: _formKey, // Assign the form key
        child: Column(
          children: [
            FilledButton(
              onPressed: () {
                setState(() {
                  _formData['title'] = _getText();
                });
              },
              child: Text('test'),
            ),
            TextFormField(
              decoration: const InputDecoration(labelText: 'Title'),
              initialValue: _formData['title'],
              onSaved: (val) => _formData['title'] = val!,
            ),
            TextFormField(
              decoration: const InputDecoration(labelText: 'Description'),
              initialValue: _formData['desc'],
              onSaved: (val) => _formData['desc'] = val!,
            ),
            ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                _saveFormData();
              },
              child: Text('Save'),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  void _saveFormData() {
    if (_formKey.currentState!.validate()) {
      _formKey.currentState!.save();
      debugPrint("_formData-----------$_formData");
    }
  }

  String _getText() {
    return DateTime.now().toString();
  }
}
```